# What is the difference between using -d and -D when deleting a branch in git?

Tags: git, version-control

Can some body please help me to understand what is the difference between following two git commands?

```
$ git branch -d testing
```

and

```
$ git branch -D testing
```

When should we use -D?

Comment: The differences between the two flags are explained in the [`git-branch` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch). Have you had a look at it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`git branch -d` is for deleting branches that are fully merged in its upstream branch or to HEAD if you don't have a upstream for your branch. If the branch is not fully merged it will not perform the deletion.

`git branch -D` deletes the branch even if it's not merged.

Answer (score 4):

In complement to the other answer: think of `-D` as `-d --force`. `-d` is the safe option, you probably want to teach your fingers to use this one. When `-d` refuses to delete the branch, make sure you know what you're doing, and then use `-D`.

Actually, `-D` sounds so much like `-d --force` that you can indeed use `-d --force` since Git 2.3.